# Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-10" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: jqgrid

how are you evry body i need your  help me i have an exeption in my Java EE application using struts2, hibernate , struts-jquery-plugin and json plugin .
a i have two jsp content a grid wen i click to going to jsp contenent a grid i get this exception, please can you help me thanks.

`Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-7" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:567)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:388)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:481)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:481)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)`

Comment: i have two  classe extend in action support and many jsp

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try increasing your application heap space and restart?